# Micro frontend using module federation with EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, module, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We would like to know the feasibility of WebPack module federation build system in Ember JS App for invoking federated code from Ember App to connect with other front end codebase developed in React JS or other SPA.

Basically, we would to implement Micro-frontend using module federation approach where multiple frontends are already developed on Ember js and reactJS. In addition to that,  our usecase depends on deeplinking, datasharing  between these microfrontends.

Based on our understanding EmberJS by default uses broccoli and doesn't have support for webpack, Which is essential for Module Federation approach to accomplish Micro Frontend.

Looking forward for some pointers here

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this vite demo: https://github.com/lifeart/demo-ember-vite -- given that this is possible, however you "normally do module federation in webpack", is how you'd do it in ember.

you can do anything modern you can imagine (if you give up the older parts of the ecosystem) -- for example, any addon not in the v2 format likely won't work with the demo'd approach.

Broccoli isn't *needed* for EmberJS, it's just what happens to be the current default build system, and Embroider is 98% compatibility, with that 2% being the easy "just use webpack" parts. Embroider is pretty good for new apps if you don't use ember-data (newer than 4.7 at the time of writing), but that's the main purpose of embroider, bring the whole rest of the ecosystem to the modern era without folks needing to re-write their apps from scratch, and have to re-solve common problems.